# liquibase: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, liquibase

Spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE приложение
до добавления зависимости с liquibase все отрабатывает корректно.

зависимости:

```
dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework:spring-context')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
        compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP')
        compile('com.oracle:ojdbc7')
        compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-oracle')
    }
```

app.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 6
      maximum-pool-size: 30
      pool-name: "isName"
      auto-commit: true
      connection-timeout: 20000
      allow-pool-suspension: false
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      jdbcUrl: ${datasource.url}
      username: ${datasource.username}
      password: ${datasource.password}
```

класс приложения

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")
@EnableServiceClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            System.out.println("Context started");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

настройка датасурса

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JdbcConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "defaultHikariConfig")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultDataSource")
    public DataSource defaultDataSource(@Qualifier("defaultHikariConfig") HikariConfig hikariConfig) {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("defaultDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

работает ок.

при добавлении liquibase соотвественно добавляю запись с указанием где смотреть файл

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: ${migration.enabled}
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/schema.change.log.yaml
```

и при добавлении этой зависимости `compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.0.0')` приложение не собирается

ошибка

```
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'registryDao' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: 
Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: 
Failed to determine suitable jdbc url
```

Comment: Я вижу runtime сообщение. Значит оно собирается, но не запускается. Посмотрите, где оно пытается найти jdbc url.

Comment: Насколько я помню, для liquibase так же надо прописывать пути к бд, пароли и т.д., иначе такая фигня и будет вылетать